# Is it good for a grpc service to accept a defined response from other grpc service as the request?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a ServiceA as below.

```
// Service definition for ServiceA
service ServiceA {
  rpc MethodA(MethodARequest) returns (MethodAResponse);
}
```

I want to create a ServiceB to handle the response from ServiceA. Can I just use MethodAResponse as the request?

```
// Service definition for ServiceB
service ServiceB {
  rpc MethodB(MethodAResponse) returns (MethodBResponse);
}
```

Or should I still create a `MethodBRequest` that wraps `MethodAResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Think of RPCs as similar to any function|method invocation.

There's no reason why one function cannot take as its parameter(s) the result of another function call.